# When to consider oAuth or RESTful authentication

Tags: rest, oauth

I'm currently in the process of designing an api for a link aggregator I created. The api that I am designing would simply allow users to extract data on post's made on the site, and other meta data (upvotes, comments, etc...). Would it be recommended to use oAuth or RESTFul authentication (basic auth) for this kind of situation. My goal is to simply make a GET web service for one of my sites. Furthermore, in order to broaden my knowledge on this concept, can anyone detail for me when to use oAuth authentication and when to simply use RESTful authentication (the use of tokens, basic auth, etc..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider an oAuth or REST if users must authenticate to use it. This would ensure users are who they are upon accessing. If you chose not to use that then you could simply require some sort of key in the GET. I would also consider using them if you plan on having your database manipulated through user input for added security.

Comment: Thanks for your insight Joseph!

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned "RESTful authentication". Then you should use [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/) and [not OAuth](http://oauth.net/articles/authentication/).

Perhaps a better questions is why **NOT** use OpenID Connect?